# After the try block....Getting wrong startTime and EndTime while posting in backend... Let me know

Tags: javascript, mern

I'm facing a issue in startTime and endTime while posting a Ad;
for example I'm entering a startDate with time `2023-09-19T22:12:00` and endnote with time as `2023-09-19T22:13:00` on posting this in req.body I'm getting the start time and endtime as `2023-09-19T22:42:00.000Z`, `2023-09-19T22:43:00.000Z`

---

**Source Code :**

models.js:

```js
  ...
   startTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
    endTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
    },
  ...
```

controllers/ad.js :

```js
exports.addAd = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      errors: errors.array(),
    });
  }

  let {
    productName,
    category,
    basePrice,
    description,
    images, // Assuming 'images' is an object with four keys
    startTime,
    endTime,
    duration,
  } = req.body;


  console.log("req. body", req.body);
  const timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
  startTime = moment.tz(startTime,timezone).valueOf();
  endTime = moment.tz(endTime,timezone).valueOf();
  console.log("data refractures ", startTime, endTime);
  duration =  (endTime- startTime)/1000;
  // if (duration === null || duration === 0) duration = 300;
  // if (duration > 10800) duration = 3600;
  const timer = duration;
  console.log("Data", 
  startTime, endTime, duration
  );

  console.log("Data", 
  moment(startTime).format('MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss'), 
  moment(endTime).format('MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss')
  );
  try {
    let ad = new Ad({
      productName,
      description,
      basePrice,
      currentPrice: basePrice,
      startTime,
      endTime,
      duration,
      timer,
      category,
      owner: req.user.id,
      images, // Store the object with four image paths directly in the 'images' field
    });
    
console.log(ad.startTime);
console.log(ad.endTime);

    // images.forEach((image, index) => {
    //   ad.images[index] = `/upload/image/${image}`; // Store the image paths as strings
    // });

    // Create room for auction
    let room = new Room({ ad: ad._id });
    room = await room.save();

    ad.room = room._id;
    await ad.save();

    const user = await User.findById(ad.owner);
    user.postedAds.push(ad._id);
    await user.save();

    io.getIo().emit("addAd", { action: "add", ad });

    res.status(200).json({ ad, room });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ msg: "Server error" }] });
  }
};
```

**Output:**

```
req. body { productName: 'Blahh', category: 'Blahh', basePrice: '7490', description: 'Lorem ipsum', images: [ '827eb6bb-d8cd-4ec2-9610-81bfb94a17ce', '47c953f1-f057-4de1-92ef-3b5b519a6a7b', '49b2c880-8482-4203-8927-20b0fac0d0b1', '1c49a3ae-6518-4094-a2a2-7e4115c947e8' ],** startTime: '2023-09-19T22:12:00', endTime: '2023-09-19T22:13:00', duration: '60' } data refractures 1695141720000 1695141780000 Data 1695141720000 1695141780000 60 Data September 19, 2023 10:12:00 September 19, 2023 10:13:00 2023-09-19T16:42:00.000Z 2023-09-19T16:43:00.000Z**
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
req. body { productName: 'Blahh', category: 'Blahh', basePrice: '7490', description: 'Lorem ipsum', images: [ '827eb6bb-d8cd-4ec2-9610-81bfb94a17ce', '47c953f1-f057-4de1-92ef-3b5b519a6a7b', '49b2c880-8482-4203-8927-20b0fac0d0b1', '1c49a3ae-6518-4094-a2a2-7e4115c947e8' ], **startTime: '2023-09-19T22:12:00', endTime: '2023-09-19T22:13:00', duration: '60' } data refractures 1695141720000 1695141780000 Data 1695141720000 1695141780000 60 Data September 19, 2023 10:12:00 September 19, 2023 10:13:00 2023-09-19T22:42:00.000Z 2023-09-19T22:43:00.000Z**
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the expected output

```js
exports.addAd = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      errors: errors.array(),
    });
  }

  let {
    productName,
    category,
    basePrice,
    description,
    images, // Assuming 'images' is an object with four keys
    startTime,
    endTime,
    duration,
  } = req.body;

  console.log("req. body", req.body);

  // Convert startTime and endTime to 'Asia/Kolkata' time zone
  const timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
  const kolkataStartTime = moment.utc(startTime).tz(timezone);
  const kolkataEndTime = moment.utc(endTime).tz(timezone);

  console.log("data refractures ", kolkataStartTime, kolkataEndTime);

  // Calculate duration in seconds
  duration = kolkataEndTime.diff(kolkataStartTime, 'seconds');
  const timer = duration;

  console.log("Data", kolkataStartTime, kolkataEndTime, duration);

  console.log(
    "Data",
    kolkataStartTime.format('MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss'),
    kolkataEndTime.format('MMMM DD, YYYY hh:mm:ss')
  );

  try {
    let ad = new Ad({
      productName,
      description,
      basePrice,
      currentPrice: basePrice,
      startTime: kolkataStartTime.toDate(), // Convert to JavaScript Date
      endTime: kolkataEndTime.toDate(),     // Convert to JavaScript Date
      duration,
      timer,
      category,
      owner: req.user.id,
      images, // Store the object with four image paths directly in the 'images' field
    });

    // Create room for auction
    let room = new Room({ ad: ad._id });
    room = await room.save();

    ad.room = room._id;
    await ad.save();

    const user = await User.findById(ad.owner);
    user.postedAds.push(ad._id);
    await user.save();

    io.getIo().emit("addAd", { action: "add", ad });

    res.status(200).json({ ad, room });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ msg: "Server error" }] });
  }
};
```